# Finsler and Cartan Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, cartan-geometry

I know many types of geometries such as Riemannian can be seen as special cases of Cartan geometry.  I was wondering since Finsler geometries generalize Riemannian ones and Cartan generalize Riemannian also can a Finsler geometry (if so can it always) be modeled as a Cartan geometry?

If so how and when?